# Prevent batch file to show error messages when START command is executed

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple code to run a program, see below:

```
@echo off
START Apps\Test.exe
Exit
```

I want to hide error message when the desired file doesn't exist:

```
Windows cannot find 'Apps\Test.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

This  `START Apps\Test.exe >nul 2>nul` doesn't work.

In addition, I don't want to remove `START` command, like this: `Apps\Test.exe` because it causes the batch file remains open until `Test.exe` is closed.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if exist "Apps\Test.exe" START Apps\Test.exe
```

should prevent your error message from appearing